# Replace with regex for min/max decimal length

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I've found on this forum the following regex to replace any number into the smallest possible decimal length:

`number.toFixed(maxDecimal).replace(/\.?0+$/, '');`

It works really well, except for one case: when number is equal to 49.9999999, it returns 5 instead of 50 when I put maxDecimal to 0. I'm a little bit lost with regex and would appreciate if you come up with a suggestion.

Comment: Instead of doing all of that, would `~~number` work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the question mark `?` since that makes `50` reduce to `5` because the regex says 0 or 1 occurrence of decimal point followed by 1 or more `0`'s. You don't want that because 0 in 50 would match that 0+ part because decimal point is optional. Use this regex this to make sure you replace only decimal part aptly.

```
>47.79955965.toFixed(5).replace(/(\.0+){0,1}$/, '');
"47.79956"
>number=49.9999999
49.9999999
> number.toFixed(5).replace(/(\.0+){0,1}$/, '');
"50"
> number.toFixed(0).replace(/(\.0+)?$/, '');
"50"
```

Comment: `/(\.0+)?$/` would work just as well, and is slightly shorter :-)

Comment: @AJNeufeld hehe yeah i guess my mind was somewhere else :P